# Use ajax in a (jquery?) loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery loop, which i want to call and use ajax for each element in the loop.

```
var splitted = [1,2,3];
var categoriesID = [4,5,6];
$.each(splitted, function(index, val)
{
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'index.php?act=ajax&op=showCategories&manufacturer='+val+'&categories='+categoriesID,
          success: function(data) {

            $(".manufacturer\\[" + val + "\\]").show();
            $(".manufacturer\\[" + val + "\\]").html(data);
            //alert('Load was performed.');

          }
        });

});
```

The problem is that i noticed that probably each element uses the same ajax connection, my results are the same - and of course for each element i should have gotten different results.

So - how i can close & re-open the ajax connection in every loop? OR is there another way to do so?

Comment: As you are using jQuery, why don't you use `$.ajax` ??

Comment: please post the `...ajax comes here..` part if you want an explanation of what goes wrong.. otherwise you should really just use the jQuery ajax methods like `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post` ..

Comment: Strange... you are using jQuery for looping (which is pretty easy in plain javascript) but not for AJAX (which jQuery does ease)

Comment: "My AJAX call doesn't work, so I'll just show everything else *except* the part that does the AJAX call."

Comment: please see my edit and my comment to the first answer. thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `categoriesID` be `categoriesID[index]`? You're sending the same categories to the server at every call. Also check that the index.php actually does send different results for different GET parameters (echo the URL and load it in the browser) and confirm it's not a server-side issue. (And to answer the original question: no, the connection is not the same for each call.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use plain js to make a simle loop, and use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to simplify ajax call to server. And for the same(bad) result that you are reciving from the server, my opinion is that you are sending or not sending the same params and then recieving same result, can you provide logic of getting the data... Ajax is asynchronous as the name says. So there is no need for open close connections, they are done in a parallel matherr. And jquery will take care of open/close. Also take a look at [how to ask a question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: i, //0,1 and 2
        url: myUrlString,
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: i have edited my post in accordance to what you've said abot jquery ajax, and its not working. can you please help me?